# create html download link to download dataframe as excel in python

Tags: python, html, amazon-web-services, pyspark, export-to-excel

can below code be modified to create download link for an xlsx file with multiple df saved as different sheets of 1 excel file
import base64
from IPython.display import HTML

```
def create_download_link( MM_df_pd, title = "Download CSV file", filename = "case_review.csv"):
   csv = MM_df_pd.to_csv()
   b64 = base64.b64encode(csv.encode())
   payload = b64.decode()
   html = '<a download="{filename}" href="data:text/csv;base64,{payload}" target="_blank">{title}</a>'
   html = html.format(payload=payload,title=title,filename=filename)
   return HTML(html)



create_download_link(MM_df_pd)`
```

I tried with saving excel file saving in s3 location first but it is long way and wont create download link, I replaced csv in code with xlsx but didnt work

Answer (score 1):

You need to use boto3 to upload your file to s3 and then create a presigned_url...

```
import boto3

def get_presigned_url(bucket:str, key:str, exp:int=3600):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    return s3.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                                Params={'Bucket': bucket,
                                                        'Key': key},
                                                ExpiresIn=exp)

def s3_upload_file(bucket: str, source_file: str, target_path: str):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3.upload_file(source_file, bucket, target_path)

df.to_csv("filename.csv") #save your csv

s3_upload_file("your_bucket","filaname.csv","your_s3_path_target")
presigned_url = get_presigned_url("your_bucket","your_s3_path_target")
print(presigned_url)
```